# how to extract a tag which does not have a particular attribute

Tags: beautifulsoup

I know that I can do:

```
soup.findAll("p", {"class" :"something"})
```

but I'm looking for p-tags that DON't have any class. how do I make sure I only get p-tags with no class attribute??

Comment: other than reading the documentation of course!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
soup.findAll('p', {'class': None})
```